# SHIFT-JIS ascii support

Tags: qt, ascii, codec, shift-jis

I want a clarification about SHIFT-JIS characters set.  Is ASCII a subset of SHIFT-JIS character set similar to UTF-8. If a file has mix of SHIFT-JIS and ASCII. how can we read the same using QT codecs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ASCII a subset of SHIFT-JIS character set similar to UTF-8

No: the backslash (0x5C) is missing from SHIFT-JIS and being replaced by a Yen currency symbol.

> If a file has mix of SHIFT-JIS and ASCII. how can we read the same using QT codecs.?

By using QTextCodec do properly decode the various pieces; however, detecting how each part is encoded is up to you...

Comment: QTextcodec("SHIFT-JIS") and pass a file which has both ASCII and SHIFT-JIS does it read properly. I even it tested the same and it seems to read all the ASCII characters but i am not able to verify if Japanese characters are read properly.